# Writing Sensor Data in Single Row in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write data coming in from 2 sensor nodes to a CSV file using Python. Communication is done via Xbee Series 1 in AT mode, with the Xbee End Devices at the 2 sensor nodes passing data to an XBee coordinator connected to my computer. These data would then have to be written to a CSV file. The sensors are connected to an Arduino.

The current problem I am facing, is that sensor data coming in from the 2 nodes are written in this way in the CSV file:

[image: The yellow area represents a block of data coming in from the 2 sensor nodes, split into 2 rows at the time 10:48:16 (HH:MM:SS). The green area represents the next block of data in the next second.]

However, I would like the data format to be: i.e. have data from 2 sensor nodes being written into a single row in an instance.

[image: One row of data contains data from 2 sensor nodes.]

My Python code for writing the CSV files below is:

```
import serial
import time
import csv

# Arduino
arduino = serial.Serial('COM11', 9600, timeout=1)

time.sleep(3) # wait for Arduino to initialize

while True:
    for datastring in arduino:
        datastring = datastring.strip()  # removes whitespaces and newline char

        if datastring:
            datasplit = datastring.split(',')  # Splits line of txt -> array of strings composed of EA individual sensor data
            field1 = datasplit[0]
            field2 = datasplit[1]
            field3 = datasplit[2]

            with open('testing1.csv', 'ab') as csvfile: # 'ab' to remove newline char after each print
                field1 = field1.replace('\n',"")
                sensor_fields = [field1, field2, field3, time.strftime("%H%M%S")]
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(sensor_fields)
```

May I ask where did I go wrong in my code? Thank you all so much! :)

Comment: Where in this code are you trying to combine two sensor nodes?

Comment: also you're constantly opening and closing the file in every loop, highly inefficient

Comment: @StephenRauch I have serial data coming in from two sensor nodes, to be fed into a computer. As the data is sent in packets by the Xbee modules, and I get 3 sets of data per node, I have split the data into 3 sets as seen in the Python code above: datasplit[0] to datasplit[2]. Thank you for your kind help! :)

Comment: @aws_apprentice Oh dear. I see May I ask if there is a better way to implement this? (: Thank you for your kind help! :)

Comment: `datastring` is still one event from arduino.  And it appears to be three columns, but you claim to have more columns than that.  Where are these other columns supposed to come from?

Comment: `arduino` is one iterator but how is it being populated by these two sensor nodes or does it keep the uniform pattern of node1, node2...

Comment: @StephenRauch I am sorry that my poor phrasing has led you to misunderstand my situation. I did not claim to have more columns that three columns, rather, I would like to have sensor inputs from the 2nd node (in green) to be beside the 1st node (yellow0, not below the 1st node~

Comment: I understood that.  What is not clear is where that data is supposed to come from.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I see~ It keeps the uniform pattern of node1, node2, etc, I think. This is because the data format for both sensor nodes are:

Light sensor, Ultrasound sensor, PIR sensor\n (this would be the print out from Arduino Serial Monitor)

Comment: @StephenRauch I see~ The data comes from a bunch of sensors attached to an Arduino which is connected to an Xbee. I have 2 sets of this is two corners of my room. (I shall call them nodes from here.)

These 2 nodes TX sensor data to an Xbee coordinator connected to my computer via serial communications.

May I ask if what I am saying makes sense? :) Thank you so much for your kind patience. :)

Comment: No this does not make sense.  From the code you only have one data source: arduino.  How do you expect to see multiple data sources?

Comment: @StephenRauch I am not sure why but I definitely see 2 data sources because the items in the green row are coded with a 't' at the end, while the items in the yellow row are coded with a 'b'. These are coded from Arduino so I am sure I have data coming in from 2 sources~ :)

Comment: OK.  So, the way you distinguish is based on a string suffix? Why did you expect me to guess this?  Now as I stated earlier, you have no code that tries to distinguish between different data sources.  Would it not be a good idea to look at the data from arduino and try to tell which source it is from?  Python has a string function `endswith()`

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes, I distinguish it based on a string suffix. I am really sorry about this. I did not mean to make you guess it. I think I am too tired from debugging this for an extended period of time and am not thinking very well now. :( I shall take a look at the function you have mentioned. Thank you. :)

Do you mean I should let Python tell from which source the data is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression that your difficulty comes from the fact that there are two alternating messages from the serial port. You need to synchronize the CSV write to be when you have complete data, storing the partial data from the first message in the mean time.

```
import serial
import time
import csv

arduino = serial.Serial('COM11', 9600, timeout=1)

time.sleep(3)

with open('testing1.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    data = []
    while True:

        for datastring in arduino:

            # one should really put some error checking and reporting on the input data
            # as it is coming from an uncontrolled external source
            fields = datastring.strip().split(',')
            fields[0] = fields[0].replace('\n', '')

            # We need to store first set of fields until the second set has been read.
            # first set is tagged '665b'
            # The list data is being used as storage and to indicate that the first line has been read
            if fields[0] == '665b':
                data = fields

            # check if we have complete data from both sensors and write out if so.
            # and ignore if alternating data is out of sync (i.e. first time round)
            elif len(data) == 3 and fields[0] != '665b': 
                writer.writerow(data + fields + [time.strftime("%H%M%S")])
                data = []
```

I would strongly recommend that you check the format of the data that you read and report errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help! ^^ I will try your code later as I was cautioned of formatting my data in the format:

665b, 0b, 1b (for example)

as it would make it machine learning unfriendly. I have changed the data instead, to:

b665, 0, 1

and I will now find the start character of every data sent by my Xbee. As I have 2 sensor nodes - one at the table, and another at my bed, I have the following:

b665, 0, 1
t255, 1, 0 (for example) 

t -> table; b -> bed

I will think of how to adapt your code into my situation. :) Thank you once again! ^^

Comment: I wonder if you need the `while True:` loop, i would expect that the `for d in arduino` loop would keep going until the serial link is lost.

Comment: I see~ Thank you for your feedback. I have re-written my entire code and I will post it up in my original post later, as an edit. My code now works, but it still has a bit of a problem which I would like to consult the community.

May I ask if this will be confusing? Thank you so much once again for your kind help. :)